# How to show an multidimensional object using in HTML table page

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the given below object and I wanted to get the output as attached png file in HTML as shown in the attachment. In the given object the "dayCalendarRows" can be N numbers of records and each record can be editable and that is also shown in an image. I can be either in standard HTML table or Material Table.

```
[
    {
        "DayId": 3,
        "DayName": "Wed",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 3,
                "DayName": "Wed",
                "DayHeader": "Wed",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Wed(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 2,
        "DayName": "Tue",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 2,
                "DayName": "Tue",
                "DayHeader": "Tue",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Tue(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            },
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": "2ceff4ad-fcfd-4169-bb23-d6769b1167e6",
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 1,
                "Day": 2,
                "DayName": "Tue",
                "DayHeader": "Tue",
                "WeekName": "Previous week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Tue(Previous week)",
                "IndexNumber": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 5,
        "DayName": "Fri",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 5,
                "DayName": "Fri",
                "DayHeader": "Fri",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Fri(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 4,
        "DayName": "Thu",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 4,
                "DayName": "Thu",
                "DayHeader": "Thu",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Thu(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            },
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": "2ceff4ad-fcfd-4169-bb23-d6769b1167e6",
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 1,
                "Day": 4,
                "DayName": "Thu",
                "DayHeader": "Thu",
                "WeekName": "Previous week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Thu(Previous week)",
                "IndexNumber": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 0,
        "DayName": "Sun",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 0,
                "DayName": "Sun",
                "DayHeader": "Sun",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Sun(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            },
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": "ef35c158-41b4-4430-bbdd-15de415736d0",
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 0,
                "DayName": "Sun",
                "DayHeader": "Sun",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Sun(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": 1
            },
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": "1ef22a16-3613-493a-9fe8-ca98d7100357",
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 0,
                "DayName": "Sun",
                "DayHeader": "Sun",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Sun(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 1,
        "DayName": "Mon",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 1,
                "DayName": "Mon",
                "DayHeader": "Mon",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Mon(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DayId": 6,
        "DayName": "Sat",
        "MealGroupId": null,
        "dayCalendarRows": [
            {
                "ICustomerId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "ICustomerDGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "Inherited": false,
                "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "BCDinerGroupId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "MealCategoryId": null,
                "MealClosingTimeGroupId": null,
                "MealDeliveryTypeId": null,
                "MealGroupName": null,
                "DeliveryMomentName": null,
                "DeliveryMethodName": null,
                "OnHolidayText": null,
                "WeekDay": 0,
                "DaysBefore": 0,
                "OnHoliday": false,
                "Week": 0,
                "Day": 6,
                "DayName": "Sat",
                "DayHeader": "Sat",
                "WeekName": "Current week",
                "PreDeliveryWeekName": "Sat(Current week)",
                "IndexNumber": -1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is what I have done till now but its showing correct for only one record if there are multiple records then its not giving me proper output:

```
<table class="mat-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="mat-header-row">
                    <th class="mat-header-cell">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th class="mat-header-cell" *ngFor="let header of deliveryCalendarDataList">{{header.dayName}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="mat-row">
                    <td class="mat-cell">
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Meal Group'| translate}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Delivery Method'| translate}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Delivery Moment'| translate}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Delivery Days'| translate}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Pre Delivery Days'| translate}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{'Delivery on Public Holiday'| translate}}</tr>
                    </td>
                    <td class="mat-cell" *ngFor="let row of deliveryCalendarDataList; let k = index">
                        <!--{{i}}-->
                        <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let dayRecords of row.dayCalendarRows">
                            {{dayRecords.dayName}}
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let dayRecords of row.dayCalendarRows">
                            {{dayRecords.preDeliveryWeekName}}
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let dayRecords of row.dayCalendarRows">
                            {{dayRecords.weekName}}
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{k}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{k}}</tr>
                        <tr class="mat-row">{{k}}</tr>
                    </td>

                 </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is how it should look

[image: This is how it should look but in this any day can have more then one record of columns and first column of left side labels should also come in next rows as well]